# Oracle - Materialized View still accessible during complete refresh. How does this work?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, materialized-views

In one of our applications, we have a massive Materialized View that refreshes three times a day, and takes seven hours to refresh.  (Not ideal, I know).  This perplexed me, because I surely thought that users and sessions could not access this materialized view while it was being refreshed, but apparently they can!.  (The type of refresh is a *complete* refresh)

During a complete refresh, to my understanding, the existing dataset is dropped and the query is then re-executed.  If this is true, then **how are users/other sessions able to access the materialized view while the materialized view is being refreshed**?

Comment: i believe this would be called: a read-consistent-view.  that means, that whenever a row is modified, the original row is preserved as it was until the end of the transaction in case someone was querying that table.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two different ways that a complete refresh can happen-- an atomic refresh or a non-atomic refresh.  An atomic refresh simply issues a DELETE to delete all the rows in the materialized view and then does an INSERT to insert the new data.  This is all within a single transaction so Oracle's standard multi-version read consistency architecture lets Oracle show other sessions the old data until the refresh completes.  In a non-atomic refresh, Oracle does a TRUNCATE on the materialized view and then a direct-path INSERT to insert the new data.  This is substantially more efficient but since TRUNCATE is DDL, it means that the old data is not visible to other sessions during the refresh.

Comment: can u choose atomic or non atomic way simply by declaring the view?

Comment: no, there is no such way to exclusively select such an update

Comment: How can I understand if a refresh is atomic or non-atomic? And how can I test the access to the MV while it's being refreshed?

Comment: @MicheleCordini - If you are using the `dbms_mview.refresh` procedure to refresh the materialized view, `atomic_refresh` is a parameter.  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_mview.htm#ARPLS67203  As for testing, just query the materialized view in a separate session while the refresh process is running.