# what happens if we access materialized view while its getting refreshed

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, materialized-views

I have a concurrent program that uses a materialized view. I want to know what will happen if its run while the materialized view is getting refreshed.
will it throw an error or not.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999958/oracle-materialized-view-still-accessible-during-complete-refresh-how-does-th

Answer (score 0):

No it will not throw error. Until view is referesh, you will not be able to see uncommitted data.